# Does this bike count as antique?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I found this bike.

[image]

The front wheel is ruined. Back is normal, but I can replace it if it worth.
It have 5 gears.
It have no serial number under BB.

So here my questions:
1. Can anyone tell when this bike was manufactured?
2. How much can a bike like this cost if fully repaired?
3. I can get any parts (good quality), so, if it worth to repair, what parts should NOT be changed (as antique), and what HAVE to be changed to modern parts?

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess it was made in from the late 70s to the 80s.  (Earlier would have cottered cranks.) Appears to be a Schwinn, which was a decent brand at that time -- not high-falutin' but a couple of grades above department store brands.  It does appear to be in good condition for its age.

Comment: (It's not what most folks would consider an "antique".  Needs to be 10-20 years older to begin to rate that designation.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielRHicks. Will it count as antique if I keep it 10-20 years? What will be (estimated) it's cost?

Comment: I'm guessing that a true "antique" bike (over 50 years old) with no particular pedigree is worth at most a few hundred dollars.  But keep in mind that, beginning about 1970, probably a million bikes a year were purchased, used 3 times, and put away in a garage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just estimating from the picture it could be late seventies early eighties
2. I see similar bikes for sale at around 150 €
3. With a bit of effort it coud be turned into a robust, efficient commuter, but it is not worth too much as antique. The frame is the best part, but equipping everything else new might get expensive. But the front wheel doesn't look that ruined, you could put new spokes. A thorough cleansing and lubing and new cables and that and the bike could go as it is. I'd put wider tires but that could be a problem with the fenders. Also old brakes like those can be weak, so that could prove a necessary change.

Comment: Yeah, the main question is whether the bottom bracket and rear hub/freehweel are in decent condition (after servicing).  If they need replacement (and you can't find a suitable "donor" bike) then it's not worth repairing.

Comment: At front wheel - I tried to true it, when the spokes blowed up. It's about to build it up with all spokes new, but I'm sure that the rim is bent.

Comment: Can you please tell, if it was your decision, would you change the wheels to modern double rim?

Comment: Me, I would get some basic wheel that looked similar, not fancy stuff. Unless you hace some special love for that bike

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at any of this or know a lot. I'm just looking around.

By the looks of it, it almost exactly looks like my Collegiate Schwinn.

I'm not sure it's the same but they have the same body style decal shape and grip. But mine only has a front brake and is a 3 speed with a coaster brake. I think it's called a 3 speed fixed gear rim/hub.

As for value I'm not sure. I got it off a private owner for $60 but, for me it would be worth the restoration it is a great and comfortable ride.

Comment: Coaster brake and fixed gear are different things. And yes, it's spelled "brake".